# Is it possible to route data between 2 wireguard devices on the same machine?

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, linux-networking, wireguard

I want to find out how much overhead wireguard creates on my machine in terms of latency. However, my server is remote, so I would like to test it solely on the machine to avoid measuring the whole network latency.

So for measuring the latency, I thought about the following setup.

I add two wireguard devices to the machine, wg0 and wg1. I then send a packet to wg0, which encrypts the packet and sends it to wg1. Wg1 then decrypts it and sends it to a local port to measure the time it takes between sending and receiving the packet.

```
My wg0 conf:

[Interface]
   Address = 10.0.0.1/24
   ListenPort = 51871

[Peer]
   AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/24, 10.0.1.1/24
   Endpoint = localhost:51872

My wg1 conf:

[Interface]
   Address = 10.0.1.1/24
   ListenPort = 51872

[Peer]
   AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/24, 10.0.1.1/24
   Endpoint = localhost:51871
```

```
I have tried using the following configuration but then I am unable to setup wg1 as the setup fails at

ip -4 route add 10.0.0.0/24 dev wg1
due to 
RTNETLINK answers: File exists

Which makes sense as because this is the IP range of the wg0 device

My wg0 conf:

[Interface]
   Address = 10.0.0.1/24
   ListenPort = 51871
   PostUp = route add -net 10.0.1.0/24 gw 10.0.0.1 
   PostDown = route delete -net 10.0.1.0/24 gw 10.0.0.1

[Peer]
   AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/24, 10.0.1.1/24
   Endpoint = localhost:51872

My wg1 conf:

[Interface]
   Address = 10.0.1.1/24
   ListenPort = 51872
   PostUp = route add -net 10.0.0.1/24 gw 10.0.1.1 
   PostDown = route delete -net 10.0.0.1/24 gw 10.0.1.1


[Peer]
   AllowedIPs = 10.0.0.1/24, 10.0.1.1/24
   Endpoint = localhost:51871
```

However, I can not get the routing set up so that my packet actually traverses the wg devices. The devices also do not perform a handshake atm. Is it even possible? Or can you recommend another setup?.

My OS is ubuntu 20.04 server. As a sidenote, I want to compare this to another measurement I took where one of the wireguard devices runs in a virtual machine. In this setup, I just ran wg0 on the host and wg1 in the VM. Basically, now I want to find out the overhead of running a wireguard gateway in a VM compared to running it natively on the machine.

**Solution**:

As suggested, I am now running the second wg device in a different namespace. The setup was straightforward because even if the wg device is moved to a different namespace, the listen-port stays in the original namespace. The RTT is about 2/3 compared to running wg1 in a Linux VM for anyone interested.

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Use network namespaces instead (or containers).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip! Got it working with namespaces. I am pretty new to this.

Comment: You can answer your own question with the working solution then.

Comment: Sorry again to suggest something: you're not supposed to add the solution *inside* the question. You're supposed to add it as an answer to the question, even if it's your own question.

Comment: No worries, I am happy to learn  ;)

Answer (score 1):

As suggested, I used network namespaces. Here is the setup I ended up with, although I didn't use config files:

Setup of the first wg device:

```
sudo ip link add dev wg0 type wireguard
sudo ip address add dev wg0 10.0.0.1/24
sudo wg set wg0 listen-port 51871 private-key ./wg0.key peer PEER1_PUBKEY allowed-ips 10.0.0.0/24 endpoint localhost:51872
sudo ip link set up dev wg0
```

Setup of the wg1 device:

```
sudo ip netns add container
sudo ip link add wg1 type wireguard
sudo ip link set wg1 netns container
sudo ip -n container addr add 10.0.0.2/24 dev wg1
sudo ip netns exec container wg set wg1 listen-port 51872 private-key ./wg1.key peer PEER0_PUBKEY allowed-ips 10.0.0.0/24 endpoint localhost:51871
sudo ip -n container link set wg1 up
sudo ip -n container route add default dev wg1
```

And then I simply run an echo client like this:

```
sudo ip netns exec container ./udp_echo_server
```